# Where to store string data in windows phone8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

There're some string data I want to display in the UI, but I don't want to write them in xaml page, where can I store them and load them dynamically when the page display? Storing them in app.xaml is a correct way?

Comment: Is this string data going to be changed by the user? Or is it fixed strings? Are you going to be or could you localize this data (e.g. a label)?

Comment: User couldn't change them, they are fixed. There's no plan to localize them, but maybe in future will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save app level static string data as Embedded Resources.

See [Using String Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965321.aspx)

This would also cater future possible need of multilanguage support

Comment: In the WP8 project, there's a Resources folder, and a AppResources.resx file in the folder, should I delete that folder and create a String folder in the project? If I do like that, there're multiple exceptions in LocalizedStrings. cs file and App.xaml.cs file.

Comment: You can open the AppResources.resx file and start adding your name, value pairs. For each language/culture, you need to create a separate AppResources file e.g. For french, you may create AppResources.fr-FR.resx

Comment: You can retrieve the value against any key in resource file like 
var value = AppResources.Key

Answer (score 0):

You can used like AppResources.resx.
It will store the string data.

You will used it like:

```
textblock.text= AppResources.xxxxxxx
```